# How to get items count on DataSourceObject without SelectCountMethod?

Tags: c#, gridview, paging, objectdatasource

Someone already made that... [ExtendedObjectDataSource](http://www.manuelabadia.com/livedemo/extendedobjectdatasource/SelectMethod.aspx)

*The **TotalRowCountParameterName** of the ExtendedObjectDataSource let us specify an output parameter for the SelectMethod in order to retrieve the total row count in case we are using paging, so there is no need for the SelectCountMethod.*

My questions is: How can I do the same thing?

I have a method that list the objects I need and it has an out parameter.

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> List(int skip, int take, out int count)
{
    /* code */
}
```

I want the the `ObjectDataSource` set the total rows with the out parameter in my select method. How can I achieve this?